# Program crashes when inserting values into large array C

Tags: c

I'm trying to do a homework assignment to measure the size of the L2 cache.  I'm trying to create and fill a large array (too big for the cache) with random integers, which I'll then walk over in varying step sizes and benchmark the performance.

The problem I'm having is when I allocate memory for the large array and then start filling the array with random integers between 1 and 100, the program crashes (stack overflow?).

I'm very new to c programming unfortunately.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int buffSize = sizeof(int) * 2000000;

    int * buff = (int*) malloc(buffSize);


    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < buffSize; i++)
    {
        int r = rand() % 100 + 1;

        buff[i] = r;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you checking the return value of `malloc`?

Comment: The error occurs when i = 2000000.  The variable you allocated has room for 2000000 entities each sizeof(int). making bufsize == (4 bytes) * 2000000 == 8000000).  Try `for (int i = 0 i<2000000;i++);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < buffSize; i++)
```

You are going too far. You only need to go up until 2000000 while `bufsize` is `2000000 * sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't creating a new array, you are allocating a block of memory based upon the size of int for your current architecture. You then proceed to treat it as an array, which works because of how c arrays and pointers work.

Once you do that, you start walking the array, but you have conflated the *length* of the array, with the *size* of the memory. If each int takes 4 bytes, then the size is `2000000 * 4` but the length is only `2000000`. This is because each int you put into it takes 4 bytes, and so you can only fit `size/4` worth of items into that space.

For what you want, just creating an array avoids malloc issues, and is more obvious:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int arr_length = 2000000;
    int arr[arr_length];

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < arr_length; i++)
    {
        int r = rand() % 100 + 1;

        arr[i] = r;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've found that I can't create an array larger than 2mb as the program just crashes when I try to access it.  That's why I use malloc.